# How to debug snakemake snakefile in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, snakemake

I'm able to run snakemake commands in Visual Studio Code. But i'm not able to make VS code pause at break points while running snakemake commands.

This is my snakefile:

```
rule all:
    input: "hello/world.txt"

rule hello_world:
    output: "hello/world.txt"
    run:
        shell('python printhello.py')
```

This is printhello.py:

```
print('hello world! file output')
pt = 1
print('After break point.')
```

I have a break point in the second line. VS code does not pause here.

This is the launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "SnakeDebug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/AV/pypsa_fes_mamba/pypsa_fes/Scripts/snakemake.exe",
            "args": [
                "--snakefile","pipeline1_01.txt",
                "--cores","1"
            ],
            "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}",
            "pythonPath": "C:/AV/pypsa_fes_mamba/pypsa_fes/python.exe",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "trace":"verbose"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think it may be difficult to debug a Snakemake workflow like this, because Snakemake parses the workflow file to determine rules, inputs, outputs, etc., and then schedules the jobs.